# How can I reset the path of FFMPEG in the VideoExport library in Processing?

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, processing

Note: This question was originally titled "How can I reset the path of FFMPEG in Java?" but, as it has been pointed out in the comments and the answer, the issue is *not* with Java, so I've changed the title to make it easier to find for others with the same issue.

---

I accidentally set the path for FFMPEG to a different folder, and I can't change it back.

I'm using Processing (the library and its IDE) and the user-created **Video Export** library to capture and write to an mp4 video file. The library required FFMPEG, so I downloaded and installed it. After I installed it, I ran the code, and the library called Java to request the path of FFMPEG. I wrongly set the path to a different folder (which I eventually deleted), and immediately realized my mistake. I ran the code again to see if I could trigger the prompt again to correct the path.

---

The console response I received was: (I'm sure most of it doesn't have to do with the actual issue. However, I wanted to show all of it in case it somehow does.)

> Oct 24, 2016 10:23:25 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences 
> WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs
> at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
> "C:...\Processing\Octree_Graphics\data\FFMPEG\ff-prompt.bat":
> CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified  at
> java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)  at
> com.hamoid.VideoExport.startFfmpeg(Unknown Source)    at
> com.hamoid.VideoExport.initialize(Unknown Source)     at
> com.hamoid.VideoExport.saveFrame(Unknown Source)  at
> Octree_Graphics.draw(Octree_Graphics.java:90)     at
> processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2399)     at
> processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$DrawListener.display(PSurfaceJOGL.java:731)
> at
> jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:692)
> at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:674)
> at
> jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:443)
> at
> jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1293)
> at
> jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
> at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:759)   at
> com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:81)
> at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:452)
> at
> com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$MainTask.run(FPSAnimator.java:178)
> at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)   at
> java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) Caused by:
> java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
> file specified    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)  at
> java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:386)    at
> java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)     at
> java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)  ... 17 more
> VideoExport error: Ffmpeg failed. Study
> C:...\Processing\Octree_Graphics\basic.mp4.txt for more details.

---

I need to find a way to reset the path of FFMPEG that Java has. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the library, but I haven't tried Java (I don't want to mess with anything it has in its current state).

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you set the path of ffmpeg? Where did you set this path? Can you look in your environment variables and change it there?

Comment: @Kevin - When the code was first run, a dialogue box for windows explorer (like the ones when you open a file in some kind of editor program) appeared. I went to the folder I believed it was installed in and hit Enter. Java now has the wrong path of ffmpeg (the actual installed one is set in the environment variables as C:\FFMPEG). I can't change the path that I accidentally selected for Java. (The path selected is C:\...\Processing\Octree_Graphics\data\FFMPEG\ff-prompt.bat)

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling the library (not ffmpeg)?

Comment: I did. I uninstalled the library, removed the library's code from the file and saved it, and then reinstalled it and added the code again. Besides, in the error message I received, it basically stated it was _Java_ itself that had the path wrong. The path is saved in Java and not the library.

Comment: Have you checked your environment variables, specifically the `PATH` variable?

Comment: Do you mean the `PATH` as in the Windows environment variables? I have set that variable to (after what was already there) `;C:\FFMPEG\ff-prompt`. I can type `ffmpeg -version` into CMD and it will display the FFMPEG version, verifying that it is installed:

`C:\...>ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-82095-g5867234 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)`

Comment: You could try looking in your Processing preferences, or uninstalling Processing (including manually deleting the preference files) and reinstalling.

Comment: After searching, I found a function within the Video Export library itself:

`public void forgetFfmpegPath()`

This function should delete the path, but I can't figure out exactly how/where to call the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, from what I can tell, this is merely inside the library in Processing, not inside of Java itself.

I have found you can reset the ffmpeg directory by running the 
".forgetFfmpegPath();" method on the VideoExport object. You only need to run it once then you can remove it.

Inside the Video Export docs the method has the description "Makes the library forget about where the ffmpeg binary was located."

You can find the documentation of the method in the VideoExport documentation, which can be found in the Processing IDE at "Help -> Libraries Reference -> Video Export". (Note the VideoExport library must be installed)

I understand this is two years old, but I am here for other people who have this issue. 
I just had this issue and found this question, but there was no answer, so I am giving the answer I found worked.

Comment: Totally forgot about this question (and my account), but I've just gone ahead and accepted this answer. From what I remember, the `forgetFfmpegPath()` method _was_ how I ultimately solved the issue ~4 years ago. Might also be worth linking to the [online documentation](https://funprogramming.org/VideoExport-for-Processing/reference/com/hamoid/VideoExport.html#forgetFfmpegPath--).